# Examples of magento 1 modules that works with 3-rd party API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, search

Recently I started to work with Magento 1, so want to learn how to do things right. Now I have some task - search through 3-rd party API (I am interesting how Magento works with another API, not own Magento REST API).
It is difficult to understand how can I pass some data (response from API service) from the controller to blocks. There are different ways to do it, but which one is better?
And other good practices.

Will be very thankful for any examples or articles...